# Differentiating user-defined Variables when using Keras layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to multiply a Keras layer with my own Variable.

Then, I want to compute the gradients of some loss relative to the variables I have defined.

Here is a simplified MWE of what I am trying to do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = input_shape = tf.keras.layers.Input((10,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(x)

s = tf.Variable(tf.ones((5,)))
x = x*s

model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_shape, x)

X = tf.random.normal((50, 10))  # random sample

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(s)
    y = model(X)
    loss = y**2

print(tape.gradient(loss, s))  # why None ??
```

The `print` prints `None`... why?

Notice that I am using eager-execution (TF version 2.0.0).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my problem by sub-classing `Model` and creating my variable inside the model:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
        self.s = tf.Variable(tf.ones((5,)))

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense(inputs)
        x = x * self.s
        return x
```

Alternatively, defining my own custom layer also works.

There must be some magic going on whereby variables not inside a model are not backpropagated (like in PyTorch).

I will leave the question open because I am curious as to why my code was not working and what a simpler fix would look like.

Answer (score -1):

This might be the explanation.  Based on reviewing the documentation, I'm suspecting that the issue is the differentiation with respect to the model layer "s" (or any other layer say "x") might not be a meaningful calculation.  For example, it is possible to do this:

```
print(tape.gradient(loss, model.variables))
```

and obtain the gradients with respect to the model weights/parameters, but differentiating the model with respect to a "layer" is not appropriate.  This is my speculation at this point.  I hope this helps.

Comment: If you check my code more carefully, you see that `s` is not a layer. It's a variable.

Comment: @RicardoCruz I'm glad you found a solution.  I was trying to convey the same idea in my response above, but perhaps not clearly.  In particular, the gradient can be taken with respect to model parameters ("variables" defined inside the model itself) but not external "layers" - by which I meant objects outside the model.